# Ansible playbook to see memory usage of servers

Tags: ansible

I currently am trying to find out how to get the % of memory used on my server.  Or at least some sort of information regarding the memory usage.

I know that by using the following

```
---

- hosts: all
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
  - name: run uptime
    shell: uptime
    register: uptime
  - name: show uptime
    debug: var=uptime
```

I'm able to see the uptime, but not sure what I have to modify to see the memory?  Even if I could see just the total memory of the server and the memory used it would be useful

Comment: Your question is more Linux-based than about Ansible, but you'll be interested in `free` tool, e.g. `free --mega` or `free --giga`. With Ansible, you can always use [`setup`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/setup_module.html) module to gather facts about remote hosts as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try running something like this, you can get memory usage and other information,

```
- name: Hardware info
 vars:
  msg: |
   RAM: {{ ansible_memtotal_mb }}
   SWAP: {{ ansible_memory_mb.swap.total }}
 debug:
  msg: "{{ msg.split('\n') }}"
```

Or you can also try running some shell command using grep/awk or something like `cat /proc/meminfo` or `vmstat` to get the memory usage on your servers and grab them in some file or something via output of ansible.